# Multiple Occupancy Sensors to control hot water return pump

Tags: electrical

Can multiple occupancy sensors be used to control a domestic hot water return pump system?
A sensor in each of three bathroom locations wired parallel to start one common low wattage return pump.
A temperature switch would interrupt circuit when return water temp reaches 100 deg F.
Do the sensors need to steal power to run from a closed circuit? This closed circuit is not there in this case.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you want an occupancy switch to control a hot water pump?

Comment: @ojalt -- hot-water-on-demand basically -- look up the Metlund D'MAND system.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the sensors in the bathrooms are low voltage, say 24V, and rated OK for parallel operation.  Also assuming that the relay that runs the pump is the same low voltage.  Generally the sensors will have three wires, positive in, negative / common in, and switched out.  Let's say it's black, white, and red.

In the basement, you'd connect the all the blacks from the occupancy sensors to 24V+, all the whites to common, and all the reds to run them in parallel.

Then to run in series with the temperature sensor, you'd tie the reds to the black of the temperature sensor, the white of the temperature sensor to the other whites, and the red of the temperature sensor to the coil / primaray + terminal of the relay that runs the pump.

The white of the coil of the relay that runs the pump would tie to all the other whites.  The secondary / contacts of the relay would switch power form the pump.

Answer (score 0):

the sensors I use are 120Vac the red wire would need to go with the ground and neutral from each sensor back to the pump
the 3 neutrals connected to the pump white, the grounds to the pump case ground, and the 3 red’s tied to the pump hot or black wire.
THIS IS VERY VERY IMPORTAND!
they also all have to be on the same leg your house has 2 legs if you use one from 1 leg and another room uses the other leg 
there will be a bang , your breaker(s) will trip and it will destroy your sensors at minimum.
I have many lighting circuits with multiple sensor inputs, a pump would work the same as long as the pump wattage is less than the sensor’s .